# Convert File to Base64 Synchronously

Tags: reactjs, typescript, base64, generator, axios

I am working on a react application in which i need to collect data in json format along with base64 implementation of the uploaded file .

I have read of the FileReader which takes a callback as an input to read the return base64 data.

I need to be able to convert this file input from input type=file and convert to base64 synchronously .

Can ES6 generators be used for this ? Can anyone provide me with an example ?

Comment: I think generator is for adding an input and requesting multiply output based on that. And in this particular problem you want one output from one input. So technically you can use it, but it makes no sense to me.

Comment: Async code can't be executed synchronously, at least not in a sensible manner. I'm sure there is a better way to do what you want.

Comment: You can make it "look" like synchronous code if your code is written inside of a generator function. Because you can use `yield` etc.